# Nginx reverse proxy stop domain from changing to local IP

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, proxy, certbot, nextcloud

I'm not familiar with any of this proxy stuff.

[nginx config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Ibz.png)

I can't seem to find a solution to this issue. Right now when I type ex.domain.com it redirects to the IP address 192.168.1.202. How do I get it to visit that address but keep ex.domain.com.

I have port forwarding setup for nginx and if i remove "proxy_pass" it shows the nginx page with the domain url. which is what I want.

For server_name localhost doesn't seem to make a difference.

I've tried adding

```
proxy_redirect
proxy_set_header
```

For reference this is what I did step by step for initial setup [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTruxKi9qbs&t=1161s)

Comment: Unless you have configured something, Nginx does not redirect to an IP address. Most likely your backend configuration is wrong. Your question does not show the redirect (use the CLI **curl -I example.com**), the Nginx configuration, or other details about your backed site.